# python pandas dataframe multiindex concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

how can I concat two dataframes with the same multi index in the following example?

Dataframe1:

```
EOAN
                  Close
DateTime   Stock       
2021-02-27 EOAN   8.450
2021-03-06 EOAN   8.436
2021-03-13 EOAN   8.812
2021-03-20 EOAN   8.820
2021-03-24 EOAN   9.084
```

Dataframe2:

```
SAP
                   Close
DateTime   Stock        
2021-02-27 SAP    102.06
2021-03-06 SAP    101.78
2021-03-13 SAP    103.04
2021-03-20 SAP    103.60
2021-03-24 SAP    103.06
                       0      1
```

I get following result, when the code gets executed:

```
DateTime   Stock               
2021-02-27 EOAN      NaN  8.450
           SAP    102.06    NaN
2021-03-06 EOAN      NaN  8.436
           SAP    101.78    NaN
2021-03-13 EOAN      NaN  8.812
           SAP    103.04    NaN
2021-03-20 EOAN      NaN  8.820
           SAP    103.60    NaN
2021-03-24 EOAN      NaN  9.084
           SAP    103.06    NaN
```

I get the dataframe like this:

```
for stock in stocks:

    df = pandas.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['DateTime', 'Close'])
    df['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], yearfirst=False)
    df['Stock'] = my_stock
    df = df.set_index(['DateTime', 'Stock'])
    app.data.clear()
    
    if df_all is None:
        df_all = df
    else:
        df_all = pandas.concat([df,df_all], axis = 1)

df_all.stack()
print(df_all)
```

What I try to get is the following result, that also works with more than two stocks:

```
DateTime   Stock   Close            
2021-02-27 EOAN    8.450  
           SAP    102.06
2021-03-06 EOAN    8.436  
           SAP    101.78
2021-03-13 EOAN    8.812  
           SAP    103.04
2021-03-20 EOAN    8.820 
           SAP    103.60    
2021-03-24 EOAN    9.084  
           SAP    103.06
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to concatenate along the columns, i.e., `axis = 1`? Maybe have a look at the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: yes, it seems otherwise I get no multiindex, so that I can't stack them

Comment: You do not need to use `stack`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Close': {('2021-02-27', 'EOAN'): 8.45,
('2021-03-06', 'EOAN'): 8.436,
('2021-03-13', 'EOAN'): 8.812,
('2021-03-20', 'EOAN'): 8.82,
('2021-03-24', 'EOAN'): 9.084}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Close': {('2021-02-27', 'SAP'): 102.06,
('2021-03-06', 'SAP'): 101.78,
('2021-03-13', 'SAP'): 103.04,
('2021-03-20', 'SAP'): 103.6,
('2021-03-24', 'SAP'): 103.06}})
```

Concatenating along the index will create a `MultiIndex` as the union of the indices of `df1` and `df2`. To get the desired output you may want to use `sort_index()` after concatenation:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index()
```